# Using a USB device with Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, usb, ios-simulator, barcode-scanner

So, I have this scanner device that scans barcodes. I want it to connect through the USB. I'm not sure how to get the data from the device once it gets scanned. I know it records the barcode info in hexadecimal, so when the data arrives to the application, some conversion will have to take place. But, I'm still very confused on how to actually digitally connect and communicate with the device.

I saw online to try and use IOKit.framework, but I believe it's for MAC, which I'm not using. I'm trying to do it through iOS in the iPhone simulator.

I also have a command list of hexadecimal commands I can send to the device, However, I don't know how to actually send the message to the device.

Apologies if I was a little repetitive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I got was distracted while I was writing the question. I just fixed it. The device has bluetooth capabilities, but I want to get the USB portion working first.

Comment: How do you communicate with it via USB? do you use the `/dev/cu.usbserial-fd*`? Does the scanner manufacturer provide a driver?

Comment: You will not be able to communicate with the scanner via USB on the device so why bother. All in all BT is the best and easiest way to go. You will probably need more information from the manufacturer. Do they supply an app, OSX or iOS? Mine had a sample OSX app. Once you get the data you will probably still need to convert the raw bar data to text, just guessing here but that is what I have seen. There are a lot of different barcode schemes in use.

Comment: to quickly answer your first question, yes I have the usbserial. And yes, it comes with a OSX app, but I'm trying to create my own iOS app to work with the device.

Comment: When you say "Once you get the data you will probably still need to convert the raw bar data to text.." - do you mean through the OSX application, then pass it along to the iOS application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

iOS Simulator has no access whatsoever to any USB device connected to the Mac.